# Python deepcopy() of a Decimal() object

Tags: python, class, decimal, deep-copy

I'm struggling to deepcopy() a class containing a Decimal value. So I tried deep copying a Decimal object on its own and that failed too. What am I misunderstanding here?

```
from copy import deepcopy
from decimal import Decimal

## Deepcopy an array ##
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = deepcopy(a)
a is b
# False

## Deep copy a Decimal ##
a = Decimal('0.123')
b = deepcopy(a)
a is b
# True

## Deepcopy a class containing a Decimal ##
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, dec):
        self.myDecimal = Decimal(dec)

a = A('0.123')
b = deepcopy(a)
a is b
# False

a.myDecimal is b.myDecimal
# True
```

The class copies but the decimal reference remains the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's `copy` module will not produce copies of immutable objects, that'd be very inefficient. `decimal.Decimal()` objects are immutable, so they just return `self` for copy operations:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal()
>>> d.__copy__() is d
True
>>> d.__deepcopy__({}) is d
True
```

See the [`decimal` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

> A decimal number is immutable.

Because they are immutable, there is *no point* in creating a copy; everywhere you could use the copy, you could safely use the original *too*, but without wasting the memory on two completely identical objects that can never diverge.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So a new assignment to either copy creates a new object, and the other reference will still point to the old one.

Comment: @switch_on: mutable structures that contain immutable objects will still be copied, but just share references to those immutable objects. Your first example, deep-copying a list, produces a second list object whose values are all references to the exact same integer objects the other list contains.